# How to go about setting up routing for android application user interface?

Tags: android, android-layout, routes, indoor-positioning-system

[App Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHnut.png)

I am attempting to create a small indoor position system for my university. I'm currently trying to figure out the best course of action to design a routing algorithm, and how that would work on the user interface.

For example, say the "user" is at a specific (x, y) point on the map, and I want to route them to another specific (x, y) point on the map.

My first thoughts on how to implement this is to use a GridView with maybe 30 x 50 blocks = 1500 locations. To represent a route I would set the background color to a specific block to blue. Then by chaining these blocks together it would represent the route to use.

Does this seem like a good solution? I am very new to android mobile application development.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pathfinding is a topic that well exceeds your question. To implement pathfinding in your case you would have to get your university's map not as a image but as data that the pathfinding algorithm understands.**

One of the most widely used pathfindng algorithms is A*, which is explained [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4946/introduction-to-a-pathfinding), I think it would fit your project.

To render the path in Android I would suggest using a `Canvas` which can be used to draw images (your map), lines (your path) and other graphical elements.

Comment: Could you recommend any resources for creating a Canvas object using my background image that I could break up into a grid?

Comment: One of the requirements of the A* algorithm is a defined grid for use with the algorithm. From evaluating the Android Canvas class, I do not see this functionality being included within this class. Is there any other recommendation for defining a scale-able grid that would respond to gestures like zooming / scrolling?